# Is 750 watts enough for a Ryzen 7 5800X and a MSI RTX 3080 gaming Trio Z

Tags: graphics-cards, processor, pc, power-supply, compatibility

just bought the components for my first build:

- MSI RTX 3080 gaming Trio Z
- Ryzen 7 5800X (Without an IGPU)
- Cooler Master MasterLiquid ML240L RGB V2
- ASUS ROG Strix B550-E Gaming
- PNY 3600MHZ 2x8gb RGB sticks
- MSI MPG Series A750GF 80 plus gold PSU
- Lian Li LanCool II mesh

I'm quite unsure of the motherboards power consumption but the GPU and the CPU consume from 512-475 (According to tomshardware the CPU can reach 142 watts) so will this system work fine or not.

Comment: Generally, you first ask for opinions here or r/buildapc, then buy components...

Comment: @Irsu85 I'm a noob in pc building so I just learnt about that ,I intuitively assumed that if I calculated the total power usage by adding the base wattage of each component individually it would give me an accurate answer , Luckily the power supply isn't delivered yet so will 850 watts be good if I'm not planning for near future upgrades nor overclocking ?

Comment: That is pretty lucky indeed. But don't overspec just a tiny little bit, PSU overspecing is generally better until 1.5x (also for efficiency and stability) so maybe 1000W is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not. Since the RTX 30x0 series GPU's have a lot of high power draw spikes (up to 700W for the 3090, probably something like 600W for 3080), it is generally good practice to overspec your PSU by quite a lot. (Linus Torvalds generally does x2, I do about x1.8.) This means a 1000W PSU would probably be better, also when talking about upgradability/overclockability.

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine with 750watts, I plugged in your parts list in PC part picker and the wattage was about 550 so a 750 is almost 200 watts more(counting in case fans and other peripherals) but if you want o be safe can go up a level to 800-850 watt PSU https://pcpartpicker.com/list/